# SQL data normalization chalange with example

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, normalization

I have data normalization challenge here and would be really grateful for some tips and directions.

I have excel file with very messed up data which I would like to transcribe in to SQLite database. I have cells like this (dummy example data):

```
PRINTER    COLORS_TO_CHANGE 
canon1     red and blue, purple, brown/green 
hp1        yellow/green, red, blue or purple 
canon2     brown or black/red, blue or green and purple 
epson1     red, green, blue
```

I normalized data in to 3 tables:

```
**tbl_printer**
printer_id    printer
1             canon1
2             hp1
3             canon2
4             epson1

**tbl_colors**
color_id     color
1            red
2            blue
3            green
4            brown
5            purple
6            yellow
7            black

**tbl_grammar**
grammar_id      grammar
1               and
2               /
3               or
```

What I wish to have at the end is list of colors/color combination for each printer. Something like this:

**Canon1:**

- red and blue
- purple
- brown/green

I get it that I should create groups (for each bullet on list) and relate printers to those groups. And then create combinations from colors and grammar. And finally relate those combinations to groups. Something like this:

```
tbl_printer_groups
group_id   foreign_printer_id   bullet_group_id
1          1                    1
2          1                    2
3          1                    3
4          2                    1
5          2                    2
6          2                    3
7          3                    1
8          3                    2
9          4                    1
10         4                    2
11         4                    3
```

And after that I create combinations that fit in to each group. And this is the part where things stop for me. If tbl_colors and tbl_grammar would be the same table, lets say tbl_thesame in which data from tbl_grammar fits just bellow data from tbl_colors, I would do something like that:

```
tbl_printergroups_to_combinations
combination_id      foreign_group_id       foreign_thesame_id        order_in_combination
1                   1                      1                         1
2                   1                      8                         2
3                   1                      2                         3
4                   2                      5                         1
5                   3                      4                         1
6                   3                      9                         2
7                   3                      3                         3
8                   4                      6                         1
9                   4                      9                         2
10                  4                      3                         3
11                  5                      1                         1
12                  6                      2                         1
13                  6                      10                        2
14                  6                      5                         3
15                  7                      4                         1
16                  7                      10                        2
17                  7                      7                         3
18                  7                      9                         4
19                  7                      1                         5
...                ...                    ...                       ...
```

Where I get lost is how do I do this from 2 separated tables. I can't group data in one, I can't put foreign keys and relations in same table in different columns since some bullet groups don't have tbl_grammar info and it would be bad practice to leave cells empty/fill them with something nonsensical.

So only choice is to separate data in another parent-child relation but then I'm not sure how to make sure to impose order of discrete pieces of information when I query data and finally print a string.

Any kind of directions/help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Having empty fields it not necessarily bad.

Comment: Normalization doesn't introduce new id numbers where there were none before. There's no such thing as "every table has an id number" normal form. There might be good reasons to introduce id numbers, but there's no reason to call that process normalization.

Comment: @CL. But it is to be avoided if possible, right? Could you please provide any example where having empty fields in table would be preferable and good RDB design?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', thank you for clarification. What is correct terminology for process above? Should I use just "Question about RDB design" or something like that?

Comment: With respect to the printer 'canon1', what's the difference in meaning between data like this, `red and blue, purple, brown/green`, and data like this, `red, blue, purple, brown, green`?

Comment: What does your family tree database store as father when you've reached Adam? Anyway, the problem here appears to be that nobody understands the colors grammar.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' - this is example data, so no direct correlation to real world. But imagine there would be more cartridge types than YCMK or RGB. Relation would be that some colors can be changed in combination since they are in same cartridge. You change red AND blue if you change this cartridge... But then again, you could also just fill up one color in cartridge so backward query must be possible to. For instance, which printers need color brown? That's why I must separate brown/green cartridge in composing pieces of information which is colors and "grammar".

Comment: @CL.It doesn't store anything. Record does not exist if there is no data for it. Every family tree database have last record which is last known ancestor. And I don't think adding another record with empty values for next "unknown" ancestor would add any informational value to such RDB.

`tbl_ancestor
ancestor_id  ancestor_name
1            Jože
...          ...
9998         Seth
9999         Adam

tbl_father
father_id   foreign_ancestor_id    father_name
1           1                      Slavko
...         ...                    ...
9997        9998                   Adam`

Comment: @CL.Oh, I get it now. You would construct database with one table with additional column father. And value in last field for unknown father (and unknown fathers in between) would be empty.
I hope I explained my pickle with "grammar" in answer to Mike. If I'm unclear and you need additional explanation and perhaps another example, please let me know.

Comment: With respect to the printer 'canon1', what exactly does data like this mean:`red and blue, purple, brown/green`?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' like I said in previous replay,it is mandatory combination of colors. Let's say color cartridge. We have color cartridge "red and blue", and we have color cartridge "purple",and finally color cartridge "brown/green" in printer canon1. So when I check for canon1 output must be "red and blue","purple" and "brown/green" exactly. Not just red, blue, purple, brown and green. But then again I also need to query in other direction: which printers have cartridge that uses color "purple" -> canon1, hp1 and canon2. I see only 2 possible solutions and I'm not fond of any of them:

Comment: 1. create intermediate table tbl_cartridges with many-to-many relation to tbl_colors and many-to-many relation to tbl_printer
2. splitting example table tbl_printergroups_to_combinations in 2 tables , where one would contain foreign_color_id (one-to-many relation to tbl_colors) and other foreign_grammar_id (one-to-many relation to tbl_grammar), and both would contain order_in_combination information and relate one-to-many to tbl_printer_groups.

First option seems redundant with duplicated information. Second option is for now my go-to-method, but I wonder if there is no better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add each combination of colors to the tbl_colors table if that does not work then you could do something like this:

```
PrinterId ColorId GrammarId GroupId
1         1       1         1
1         2       1         1
1         6       0(add none) 2
1         4       2         3 
1         3       2         3
```

You can even take out the grammarid column from the above and add another group_grammar_mapping table

```
Group_Grammar_MappingId GrammarId GroupId
1                       1         1   

PrinterId ColorId Group_Grammar_MappingId
1         1       1         
1         2       1
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is right solution. For instance, if I read your table correctly, I would get for groupId 1-> "red and green and". I could use 0 (add none) in second row for GrammarId, but I feel uncomfortable with empty/nonsensical fields in column for foreign keys just because of exceptions in data.

Also, I wish to strictly specify order between ColorId and GrammarId. Which would only be possible if I introduce 2 another columns for each of *Id own. Did I perhaps misinterpret your answer? Thank you anyway!

Comment: you just insert the grammar between the 2 colors. select colorid, printerid, groupid and grammarid into the temp table. Then create a string with the colors and grammar in between them.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you need to have tbl_grammar?
Why can't each color combination be in fact a separate colour in tbl_colors? E.g.

```
color_id     color
1            brown or black/red
2            brown
3            black/red
```

etc.

Comment: tbl_grammar is needed because I need backward queribility (if this is even a word :)). For instance I wish to perform query to retrieve all missing colors for selected printer and in other direction query that retrieves all printers with missing selected color. For instance, if I would query for purple I would like to get canon1, hp1 and canon2.

As far as I see it sepparating tbl_printergroups_to_combinations in 2 tables where one would contain foreign_group_id, grammar_id and order_in_combination and other one foreign_group_id, color_id and order_in_combination is the way to go.
...to long..

Comment: ...to long... 

And then be very carefoul in data input not to mix order_in_combination between both separated tables and then join data in query itself.

But that feels cumbersome and I'm not sure it's best practice and I wonder if I'm missing something obvious.